# Comic book about a scientific experiment going wrong and turning people into monsters

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comic about 25 years ago. A bunch of people in a village or small town were performing scientific experiments with some substance. The experiments go horribly wrong and people turn into monsters, but it eventually gets fixed, and it all only lasted a night, I think.

In the end, the main doctor was turned into a toad and it read something like: *"And by morning, only the Dr Toad in the grass was all that remained from that dreadful night."*